# Getting "null" when extracting string using REGEXP_EXTRACT in Tableau

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I have been trying to use the REGEXP_EXTRACT function in Tableau without success (see image below). I have a string column 'FOB', and I want to extract the leading capital letters. Sometimes there's a dash following the capital letters, sometimes not, so I used the following syntax in the created field 'Advertiser':

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([FOB],'^[A-Z]*')
```

However, this produces a column full of "null". The weird thing is even if I changed the pattern from '^[A-Z]*' to 'SDM', it was still the same. It just seems that Tableau is not regex enabled...

I did check my regex online [here](https://regex101.com/) and it worked... getting really confused, any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are these capital letters always the first?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to extract the first character in each *[FOB]* column cell, you need to use `^` anchor and a `[A-Z]` character class, *but also* you need to wrap the pattern with a *capturing group* (i.e. paired parentheses, `(...)`) to tell Tableau you need to extract this pattern part:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([FOB],'^([A-Z])')
                       ^     ^
```

To extract all (one or more) leading capital letters, add `+`:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([FOB],'^([A-Z]+)')
                             ^
```

See [Mark Jackson's regex blog excerpt](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2015/6/become-regular-regular-expressions-39802#O9FYD2Z7jgzfAKgP.99):

> The whole pattern is wrapped in parenthesis to tell Tableau what part of the pattern to return. This is an update from the earlier beta version I was using when I created this post. The nice thing about this addition is that Tableau lets you pattern match on a larger portion of the string, but allows you to return a subset of the pattern.